# Android AlarmManager is not working at proper times

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I have tried to use setRepeating function for AlarmManager with half an hour breaks.But it keeps giving me the alarm at erratic times..My code is

MainActivity.java

```
package com.knby.alarmmanagerdemo;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private  PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
        Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.startAlarmAt10);
        Button b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.stopAlarm);



        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                AlarmManager manager1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,14);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

                manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),60*1000*30, pendingIntent);


            }
        });

        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Alarm Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

AlarmReceiver.java

```
package com.knby.alarmmanagerdemo;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Kevin on 7/17/2016.
 */
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running bro!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Log.i("Errore","Toast?");
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.knby.alarmmanagerdemo">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
            >
        </receiver>
    </application>


    <!-- Will not be called unless the application explicitly enables it -->


</manifest>
```

And my logs

```
07-23 15:19:47.770 20447-20447/com.knby.alarmmanagerdemo W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.knby.alarmmanagerdemo-1/lib/arm
07-23 15:19:47.977 20447-20447/com.knby.alarmmanagerdemo W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.knby.alarmmanagerdemo-1/lib/arm
07-23 15:19:48.146 20447-20447/com.knby.alarmmanagerdemo W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
07-23 15:19:48.377 20447-20485/com.knby.alarmmanagerdemo I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (Ifd751822f5)
                                                                       OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.06.00.05
                                                                       Build Date: 01/26/16 Tue
                                                                       Local Branch: AU12_SBA
                                                                       Remote Branch: 
                                                                       Local Patches: 
                                                                       Reconstruct Branch: 
07-23 15:19:48.379 20447-20485/com.knby.alarmmanagerdemo I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-23 15:20:35.339 20447-20447/com.knby.alarmmanagerdemo I/Errore: Toast?
07-23 15:21:24.484 20447-20447/com.knby.alarmmanagerdemo I/Errore: Toast?
07-23 15:24:00.671 20447-20447/com.knby.alarmmanagerdemo I/Errore: Toast?
07-23 15:27:01.944 20447-20447/com.knby.alarmmanagerdemo I/Errore: Toast?
07-23 15:30:25.860 20447-20447/com.knby.alarmmanagerdemo I/Errore: Toast?
```

Comment: The alarm for `b3` is set to repeat every 30 _seconds_, not minutes, and both of the `AlarmManager` methods you're using are inexact since KitKat. If you want an exact alarm, you need to use an exact method, and set the alarm again for the desired interval each time it fires. Please consult the docs for [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Comment: But i don't press b3,i only pressed b1

Comment: Then cut the code in your question down to just the relevant stuff; the minimum necessary to reproduce the described behavior. Make sure you run that minimal code, too, to ensure you're still seeing the same issue, and that it wasn't just an error in your original implementation or testing.